# Extract elements common in all column groups

Tags: r

I have a R dataset x as below:

```
  ID Month
1   1   Jan
2   3   Jan
3   4   Jan
4   6   Jan
5   6   Jan
6   9   Jan
7   2   Feb
8   4   Feb
9   6   Feb
10  8   Feb
11  9   Feb
12 10   Feb
13  1   Mar
14  3   Mar
15  4   Mar
16  6   Mar
17  7   Mar
18  9   Mar
19  2   Apr
20  4   Apr
21  6   Apr
22  7   Apr
23  8   Apr
24 10   Apr
25  1   May
26  2   May
27  4   May
28  6   May
29  7   May
30  8   May
31  2   Jun
32  4   Jun
33  5   Jun
34  6   Jun
35  9   Jun
36 10   Jun
```

I am trying to figure out a R function/code to identify all IDs that exist **atleast** once in every month.
In the above case, `ID` `4` & `6` are present in all months.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, split the `df$ID` by `Month` and use `intersect` to find elements common in each sub-group.

```
Reduce(intersect, split(df$ID, df$Month))
#[1] 4 6
```

If you want to subset the corresponding data.frame, do

```
df[df$ID %in% Reduce(intersect, split(df$ID, df$Month)),]
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', get the row index (`.I`) where the number of unique 'Months' are equal to the number of unique 'Months' in the whole dataset and subset the data based on this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[uniqueN(Month) == uniqueN(df1$Month)], ID]$V1]
#    ID Month
# 1:  4   Jan
# 2:  4   Feb
# 3:  4   Mar
# 4:  4   Apr
# 5:  4   May
# 6:  4   Jun
# 7:  6   Jan
# 8:  6   Jan
# 9:  6   Feb
#10:  6   Mar
#11:  6   Apr
#12:  6   May
#13:  6   Jun
```

To extract the 'ID's

```
setDT(df1)[, ID[uniqueN(Month) == uniqueN(df1$Month)], ID]$V1
#[1] 4 6
```

---

Or with `base R`

**1)** Using `table` with `rowSums`

```
v1 <- rowSums(table(df1) > 0)
names(v1)[v1==max(v1)]
#[1] "4" "6"
```

This info can be used for subsetting the data

```
subset(df1, ID %in% names(v1)[v1 == max(v1)])
```

**2)** Using `tapply`

```
lst <- with(df1, tapply(Month, ID, FUN = unique))
names(which(lengths(lst) == length(unique(df1$Month))))
#[1] "4" "6"
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(Month)== n_distinct(df1$Month)) %>%
     .$ID %>%
     unique
#[1] 4 6
```

or if we need to get the rows

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(Month)== n_distinct(df1$Month))
# A tibble: 13 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
#      ID Month
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     4   Jan
# 2     6   Jan
# 3     6   Jan
# 4     4   Feb
# 5     6   Feb
# 6     4   Mar
# 7     6   Mar
# 8     4   Apr
# 9     6   Apr
#10     4   May
#11     6   May
#12     4   Jun
#13     6   Jun
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/):

```
tib %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::group_split(.keep = F) %>%
  purrr::reduce(intersect)

# A tibble: 2 x 1
#      ID
#   <dbl>
# 1     4
# 2     6
```

returns the desired IDs, where `tib` is a tibble containing the input data.